# how to implement youtube videos in AMP-html

Tags: youtube, pug, amp-html

I am trying to implement youtube videos within AMP articles by following the official documentation found here:

```
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-youtube/amp-youtube.md
```

But the youtube video is simply not rendering at all.

Here is what my Jade template looks like:

```
amp-youtube(data-videoid="#{videoId}", layout="responsive", width="480", height="270")
```

and the output is this:

```
<amp-youtube data-videoid="lZShEy8ILvg" layout="responsive" width="480" height="270"></amp-youtube>
```

It looks to be fine but I'm not sure why the youtube video is not being inserted into the amp-youtube tag.

Any suggestions are well appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I forgot to add the amp-youtube script in the document head...